# Excel sum cells and set result in one of these summed cells

Tags: excel, sum

I want to sum the column if the last row of the column is not empty. Then the Result of the summation should be saved in the first row, so that it is a "never ending column (but with only 4 rows) (values of A,B,C,D are entered manually except D is not empty -> A should be the sum and B,C,D should be entered manually). **EXAMPLE:**

```
A -> 4
B -> 2
C -> 5
D -> 3
E -> sum(A+B+C+D) (14)
```

Now the 4th row (D) is filled so I want to sum A+B+C+D (4+2+5+3=14)
And the Result should be saved in first row (A):

```
A -> 14
B -> (empty)
C -> (empty)
D -> (empty)
E -> sum(A+B+C+D) (14)
```

In addition to this -> the 5th row (E) should always show the sum of (A,B,C,D)

```
A -> 14
B -> 2
C -> (empty)
D -> (empty)
E -> sum(A+B+C+D) (16)
```

I hope someone can help me to do this!

Comment: `A1=4 B1=2 C1=5 D1=3`?What do you mean?

Comment: no sorry A1=4 A2=2 A3=5 A4=3

Answer (score 0):

In the desired cell you want the sum result to be in type in `=` and then click the cell which corresponds to `A` then type `+` and continue for `B,C,D`. When you're done just press enter. Then have this result and add it into another list of `A,B,C,D` for your other table.

However, you want the result to be pushed back into `A` like you may be hinting at, you cannot do that. Otherwise you'll be overwriting the equation or value, which will cause an error. Your best bet is to do the above.